# embedded jetty cannot access jsp servlet in deployment

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

While my embedded jetty application runs fine in eclipse it isnt serving up a JSP as a servlet in my deployment.  Jetty doesnt return an error but rather it simply displays the contents of my webapp dir.  I can access other servlets but not console.jsp which is set as my welcome file in the web.xml.

My code for setting up the embedded server and the web.xml are below...

```
    Server server;

    WebAppContext webappContext = new WebAppContext();
    webappContext.setContextPath("/indexers");
    webappContext.setWar(IndexerWebApp.class.getResource("/webapp").toExternalForm());

    server.setHandler(webappContext);
```

web.xml......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Indexer Control Console</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>console.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>launchTask</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hp.it.kmcs.suggest.index.web.servlets.LaunchTask</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>taskStatus</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hp.it.kmcs.suggest.index.web.servlets.GetTaskStatus</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rescheduleTask</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hp.it.kmcs.suggest.index.web.servlets.RescheduleTask</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!-- Servlet mappings -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>launchTask</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/launchTask</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>taskStatus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/taskStatus</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rescheduleTask</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rescheduleTask</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Does console.jsp really exist? If you navigate to "/console.jsp" what do you get?

Comment: Hi Tim.  All I get when i browse to it is the jsp file contents displayed in the browser.  We created a workaround by splitting the project into a standard webapp and an embedded jetty app.  The webapp (having normal webapp structure) could then be run in a second lightweight embedded jetty project (or any other web container for that matter).  Not happy that it didnt work first time though :(

Comment: I'd have to dig a bit deeper, but at first glance it looks like you don't have all the "standard" servlets setup. JSPs are handled by a special Jetty servlet mapped to "*.jsp" (etc), so if that's not mapped, you'd get JSPs served up as static content instead. Not sure why you'd be in that situation though.

Comment: Good point.  Gone a different direction with it now but will try to fish out the old project, test it and let you know.